# Watch image width and height on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an image as a map and putting markers on it (Google Maps is not an option). I am converting the markers latitude/longitude to pixels in function of the height/width of the map image.

I have this object on my controller and if I assign the height and width directly, it works like a charm:

```
$scope.dimensions: {
    width: 1280,
    height: 720
}
```

But if I try to assign it dynamically, it just doesn't work:

```
$scope.dimensions: {
    width: (document.getElementById('static-map') === null) ? 0 : angular.element(document.getElementById('static-map').clientWidth),
    height: (document.getElementById('static-map') === null) ? 0 : angular.element(document.getElementById('static-map').clientHeight)
}
```

I know at first run the element will be null, but I want to find a way to:
A) Get the size of the map image once it loads
B) As the image has a relative width to its container (100%), get my dimensions to update when the container gets resized.

Comment: Generally speaking, DOM manipulation or work shouldn't be done in a controller and instead in a directive, however... you need to set an initial width/height to the element and perhaps have a $watch on the height/width and use that? Unless that is something you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks @Euphoria, I haven't tried that (I have almost null experience creating directives); how do I access to a value set on a directive on my controller? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `angular.element` around the `clientWidth/clientHeight` stuff, or make the calls like `angular.element('#static-map').width()`. `angular.element` is used like jQuery's constructor, to find elements on a page with selectors.

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: Any progress on this?